# Does Do Not Disturb mode turn off automatically?

Tags: ios, do-not-disturb

If I turn on Do not disturb mode from control center, will it automatically turn off in the morning?

Comment: Additionally connecting the correct answers provided here back to your question, if you have a schedule AND turn it on early via the control center, it will turn back off via the schedule.   I.e. If started manually the next scheduled stop time will turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

No, just flipping it on in Control Center won't get it to automatically turn off.

To get Do Not Disturb to automatically turn off, you need to schedule it to do so in `Settings` > `Do Not Disturb` > `Scheduled`.

Answer (score -1):

Go on Settings -> Do not disturb ...

[image]

__

[image]